# How to get birth and death cerificate from Istanbul, Turkey in 1902-1905?

Tags: birth-records, death-records, 1900s-decade, turkey

How can a non-Turkish speaking amateur get a copy of a birth certificate for a grandmother born in Istanbul, Turkey (1902) and a death certificate for a grand-grand father buried at Eyup Cemetery in Istanbul, Turkey (1905)?

Or how I can find a genealogist in Turkey to help me in this research?

Comment: Welcome to G&FH.SE!  We encourage all users to take the [tour] and to read the [help] to learn more about the site.  If you have questions about how the site works, you can also read and ask questions in the companion site [Meta].  I have made some small edits to your question to fix some typos.

Answer (score 3):

I was successful in obtaining my Romanian ancestors' certificates many years ago by hiring a researcher in Romania. He went to the District Office and obtained and sent me photocopies of the certificates along with his own translation of the Romanian to English for what was a modest fee.

From [the Association of Professional Genealogists (APG) directory of members](https://www.apgen.org/directory/index.html), one professional is listed as living in Turkey and accepts clients. Another lists themselves as a specialist for research in Turkey but lives in Germany.

There is also the Board for Certification of Genealogists, but there do not appear to be any claimed specialists in Turkish research [in their membership list](http://www.bcgcertification.org/associates/index.php).

The other site that I usually try is [GenLighten](http://www.genlighten.com/), which works to connect those needing help with researchers who can help them. Their search does not list any help for Turkey, but you could contact them.

Personally I would try the APG member living in Turkey. To minimize possible problems, the APG has [an excellent page of tips about hiring a professional](https://www.apgen.org/articles/hire.html).

Answer (score 2):

First you need to know her registry details. You can get a "detailed" copy of "your" registration (also showing your 1st degree relatives with names, their parent's names, birth places, dates etc.) by applying to ANY Civil Registry Office in Turkey. Then you have the apply to THE Office of the county you're registered at. And this only first degree relatives. For a grandmother you may try your chances and ask a friendly help from the Civil Registry Officer, if unsuccesful you'll have to go through a court process.

As suggested in a previous answer it may be a good idea to get some help from a local researcher who could assist you with this as they may have connections and access to some data. I think there is a resident researcher on the APG list now.