# Obtaining 1932 birth certificate from Turkey?

Tags: 20th-century, birth-records, turkey

Can anyone advise me on how to obtain my mothers birth certificate from Istanbul, Turkey? She was born in 1932.

Comment: This related [question](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/10048/4485) may have some useful hints.

Comment: Connie, welcome. Would you mind adding a few more details, as that will help you get a better answer. For example, were your mother's parents Turkish nationals? If not, her birth certificate may have been registered with the relevant embassy, and might not appear in local records.